# What is the type of array field in telemetry called in device schema?

Tags: javascript, json, azure, azure-iot-hub

I am following the github instruction to created a simulated device model and one of the filed in telemetry is a array of 10 integers. "pm": [ 19, 4, 3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0 ]. What is the type of this field? I did not find any array/list type.

The github instruction:
https://github.com/Azure/device-simulation-dotnet/wiki/Device-Models#message-schema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is no support for an `array` type, however you can achieve that in at least two different ways.

If the array size is fixed, e.g. 10, use 10 fields:

```
"InitialState": {
    "pm_01": 0,
    "pm_02": 0,
    "pm_03": 0,
    "pm_04": 0,
    "pm_05": 0,
    "pm_06": 0,
    "pm_07": 0,
    "pm_08": 0,
    "pm_09": 0,
    "pm_10": 0
}
```

and then

```
"MessageTemplate": "{ \"pm\": [${pm_01}, ${pm_02}, ${pm_03}, ${pm_04}, ${pm_05}, ${pm_06}, ${pm_07}, ${pm_08}, ${pm_09}, ${pm_10}] }"
```

Otherwise, if the array size can change, map the values to a string (e.g. `pm_values`) in the device model script, e.g.

model:

```
"InitialState": {
    "pm_values": "0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0"
}
```

script:

```
function main(context, previousState) {

    // ... restore state ...

    // ... your logic here ...
    var pm_values = [ 19, 4, 3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0 ];

    // ... serialize pm values ...
    state["pm_values"] = pm_values.toString();

    return state;
}
```

and then inject that in the message template, using only one placeholder:

```
"MessageTemplate": "{ \"pm\": [${pm_values}] }"
```